# Not able to install dropbox Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, dropbox

My terminal emulator shows the following error while trying to install Dropbox. I need help and I am a beginner in Ubuntu.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nautilus-dropbox : Depends: dropbox but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get autoclean` then `sudo apt-get update` then install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Dropbox package from the [Dropbox site](https://www.dropbox.com/install), install it, and then install `nautilus-dropbox`. I don't think the dropbox package is available in the official repositories.